# Repeated Startup Repair on Windows 11

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-11, efi

My acer Nitro-5 went into startup repair problem a few days ago.

Below is the photo.

[windows11 startup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4nLv.jpg)

Since I have dual boot on my computer, when I start my Ubuntu, the following suggestions show up:

[Ubuntu: "A hard disk is likely to fail soon"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Z5P.jpg)

[Problem on ESP partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4nls.jpg)

So I guess the startup repair problem may be related to the first partition of the disk.

Can anyone provide any solutions to the problem? Thanks!!!

---

I run `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda1` inside my Ubuntu terminal (`/dev/sda1` corresponds to the ESP partition based on the last picture I uploaded) and it returns:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-105-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     HGST Travelstar 7K1000
Device Model:     HGST HTS721010A9E630
Serial Number:    JR1000BNHRXSXE
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 8e6d883ac
Firmware Version: JB0OA3J0
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Apr  7 05:03:05 2022 PDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   45) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 165) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   130   130   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       2
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2251
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   005    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       4140
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2098
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       65538
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       99
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       74738
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 10/47)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   072   072   000    Old_age   Always       -       851
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       13488
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 5262 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 5262 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4140 hours (172 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 28 88 d4 a6 01  Error: UNC 40 sectors at LBA = 0x01a6d488 = 27710600

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:06:19.933  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:06:16.967  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:06:14.004  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7e b8 d3 a6 40 00      00:06:14.003  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 79 40 d3 a6 40 00      00:06:14.003  READ DMA EXT

Error 5261 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4140 hours (172 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 28 88 d4 a6 01  Error: UNC 40 sectors at LBA = 0x01a6d488 = 27710600

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:06:16.967  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:06:14.004  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7e b8 d3 a6 40 00      00:06:14.003  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 79 40 d3 a6 40 00      00:06:14.003  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 01 40 d3 a6 40 00      00:06:13.992  READ DMA EXT

Error 5260 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4140 hours (172 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 28 88 d4 a6 01  Error: UNC 40 sectors at LBA = 0x01a6d488 = 27710600

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:06:14.004  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7e b8 d3 a6 40 00      00:06:14.003  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 79 40 d3 a6 40 00      00:06:14.003  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 01 40 d3 a6 40 00      00:06:13.992  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 40 00 29 66 40 00      00:06:13.982  READ DMA EXT

Error 5259 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4140 hours (172 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 28 88 d4 a6 01  Error: UNC 40 sectors at LBA = 0x01a6d488 = 27710600

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:00:13.759  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:00:10.793  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:00:07.838  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7e b8 d3 a6 40 00      00:00:07.838  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 79 40 d3 a6 40 00      00:00:07.837  READ DMA EXT

Error 5258 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4140 hours (172 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 28 88 d4 a6 01  Error: UNC 40 sectors at LBA = 0x01a6d488 = 27710600

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:00:10.793  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7b 35 d4 a6 40 00      00:00:07.838  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 7e b8 d3 a6 40 00      00:00:07.838  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 79 40 d3 a6 40 00      00:00:07.837  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 01 40 d3 a6 40 00      00:00:07.826  READ DMA EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: First, back up your data. Then, try [running smartctl](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-check-an-hard-drive-health-from-the-command-line-using-smartctl) so that you can report back what it tells you in the question.

Comment: Use a Linux Live USB to save your data, then replace the disk.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks. I have run the command line. The printed information has been added.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. Do I necessarily have to replace my disk? But I can still use my Ubuntu with my computer.

Comment: @HoiM - Yes; You need to replace your disk immediately.

Comment: @HoiM Once one part of a disk drive goes wrong, it can create debris that quickly damages the rest of the disk. It is an opportunity to replace it with an SSD, and the computer will feel faster then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise to save your data and replace the disk.

You have had some destruction on the disk, and although apparently
Windows was more affected than Ubuntu, this doesn't mean that Ubuntu
may not also fail in the future.

In particular, you had 51 reallocated sectors (sectors that died),
11 seek failures, and other various errors.

The disk is failing.
Continuing to use it is just gambling with your data.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. I have bought a new SSD and will replace the disk soon.